# Use domain of one table for criteria in another in ms Access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a report that displays 3 different numbers for each of my projects.

1. Contract Hours - Stored in projects table, 1 to 1 relationship
2. Worked Hours - Stored in linked table that will be updated using an external website reporting feature that will contain only data for the dates that are to be displayed in the report, one to many relationship needs to be a sum
3. Allocated Hours - Stored in a table in my database called allocations and contains data for all dates, one to many relationship needs to be summed.

Right now i have it set up in a way that the user has to type the data range for the report every time it is run, however the date range only actually applies to the Allocation data because the worked hours data comes filtered and the contract data is one to one.

**What I would like to do is set up a query that can see the domain of the worked hours and apply it as a date criteria for the allocated hours.**

I have attempted to use max and min values of the Worked hours and tried to get creative but I'm actually not even sure if this is possible because I cannot see any simple solution (although I know it should be possible and fairly simple)

Any help, suggestions, or recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: show some detail of tables, scripts, and platform. above 4 tags are bit broad

Comment: why did you tag mysql here?

Comment: I don't know I changed it. But I'm not really ally sure exactly what details you want. There are no scripts,  the platform is ms access.